# Python - Deleting the last line if it is a newline

Tags: python

my objective is to check the file and see if the last line is a newline(empty) and if so delete it. I've tried heaps of methods like this and etc:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".ADC"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as infile, open(os.path.join(directory, filename)) as outfile:
            lines = infile.readlines()
        if lines:
            lines[-1] = lines[-1].rstrip('\r\n')
            infile.writelines(lines)
```

also tried the readlines method with no success.

Comment: On your last line - are you meaning to write to `infile` or should you be writing to `outfile`?

Comment: think its suppose to be outfile, but didn't work. Below suggestion by @barmar was something i tried but as the file is treated as a .txt, not sure removing /n does anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".ADC"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for line in lines[::-1]:
                if line == '\n' or line == '\r':
                    lines = lines[:-1]
            print(lines)
```

Comment: This was really useful, I should have tested this with the other methods. print(lines) shows that \n was on the 2nd last line. Hence all the other empty lines did not have any newline callers. So, probably txt files can create whitespace without \n?

Comment: @amac you want to remove all `\n` from file, for example if file ends with 5 `\n` you want all to remove?

Comment: Yes, would i do a for loop with a condition?

Comment: @amac can you try it

Comment: so using a while loop. I can remove all the \n lines. however, just pondering how I can append a line after that removal.

Comment: If you're going to remove *all* blank lines, you can use `lines = lines.filter(lambda line: line not in ['\n', '\r'])`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the last line is an empty string. If it is, calculate the total size of the preceding lines, and then truncate the file to that size.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".ADC"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            if lines and lines[-1].rstrip('\r\n') == "":
                lines.pop()
                size = sum(len(l) for l in lines)
                file.truncate(size)
```

Truncating is more efficient than rewriting the whole file without the last line.

Comment: Just tried this and doesn't seem to truncate the last empty line. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Forgot that the last line will include the newline characters, so we need to strip them off before checking if it's empty.

Comment: Tried that, strips away newline characters. However, empty line remains. something wrong with the if statement?